# cannot access a git branch from a different computer

Tags: git, github

Basically i cannot see a branch on a different computer. I run

```
git branch -a
```

and on home computer I get

```
C:\learn ror\sample_app [filling-in-layout]> git branch -a
* filling-in-layout
  master
  static-pages
  remotes/origin/filling-in-layout
  remotes/origin/master
  remotes/origin/static-pages
```

On the work pc I get almost the same result, except the "filling-in-layout" branches(local and remote).

What should I do?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To share branches, you need to push your branches on the machines where they're created, and setup remote tracking branches on the other machines:

Try this, on the machine that has the branch:

```
git push -u origin <branch name>
```

and this on the machine that doesn't:

```
git fetch
git checkout <branch name>
```

Git will automatically set up a remote tracking branch named `<branch name>` if you try to check out a branch that only exists on a remote.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a tag or a branch in your machine, and when you want to share your tag or your branch in remote repository, you have to push the tag or branch in the same way you push the repository.

```
$ git checkout -b new-branch
[...]
$ git add .
$ git commit -m 'Some stuff'
$ git push origin new-branch
```

And the same with a tag:

```
$ git tag 6.7
[...]
$ git push origin 6.7
```