# git branch can't be seen from my computer at home

Tags: github

```
git checkout `branch name`
```

At work I added a new branch but in my home I can't access it. Can anyone help?

```
git pull
```

Comment: Did you push the new branch to the remote?

Comment: Yes I did push the code from work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
git fetch
```

See [cannot access a git branch from a different computer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11322582/cannot-access-a-git-branch-from-a-different-computer)

Comment: You missed the critical part of the answer you're referencing; you need to run `git push -u origin <branch name>` on the first computer before being able to access it on the second.

Comment: Thanks Ahmad it worked.....
Obsidian ahmad forget to say it maybe but I did it lol

Comment: @ObsidianAge Thanks for your reply
I told him git fetch and I suppose he already did it in the first computer
and for further info.I shared the link where the `missing code ` is there